# android: SharedFlow collected twice

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a simple `SharedFlow` in my viewModel:

```
private val _navigationEvent = MutableSharedFlow<PreCheckoutNavigationEvent>()
val navigationEvent = _navigationEvent.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily )
```

(`PreCheckoutNavigationEvent` is a sealed class)

it gets emitted like:

```
_navigationEvent.emit(/*new instance of PreCheckoutNavigationEvent*/)
```

and collected in a fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        collectWhenStarted(viewModel.navigationEvent) {
           navigate(it)
        }
}

protected fun <T : Any?> collectWhenStarted(
        flow: Flow<T>,
        collector: suspend (value: T) -> Unit
    ) =
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                flow.collectLatest(collector)
            }
        }
```

problem is `navigate()` get's executed twice with the same object.
I use `collectWhenStarted()` everywhere in the app without any issue. Only this flow is giving me problems. I even tried to collect `viewModel.navigationEvent.debounce(500)` but it still collects two emissions

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Is there any chance that this happens because of the lifecycle? You queuing `collect` 2 times, because `onViewCreated` happens before `onStart`. Both callbacks trigger `collectLatest`. Just a guess though

Comment: you should be using `viewLifecycleOwner` when touching views.

Comment: @Pawel you're right I misread the documentation at the time I wrote `collectWhenStarted()`. I'm baffled that it only happened this time and on a view that doesn't go through any lifecycle change. Feel free to post an answer with the correct solution if you want

Comment: @Steyrix no that's actually the correct place to use `repeatOnLifecycle()` according to [documentation] (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Pawel solved by doing

```
protected fun <T : Any?> collectWhenStarted(
        flow: Flow<T>,
        collector: suspend (value: T) -> Unit
    ) =
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                flow.collectLatest(collector)
            }
        }
```